# How can I read multiple files(file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt) from different threads using pthreads library?

Tags: c, multithreading, file-io, operating-system, pthreads

I want each thread to read words from one of the files (e.g., Thread 1 reads words from “file1.txt”). Currently, there are four such files.

Example: Thread1 reads file1.txt, Thread2 reads file2.txt and so on.

How can I assign one file per thread in C?

Comment: This reads like a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: For starters: `void * read_thread(void *vp) { long idx = (long) vp;  char file[100]; sprintf(file,"dictionary%ld.txt",idx);  FILE *fin = fopen(file,"r"); }  int main(void) {  const int nt = 4; pthread_t threads[nt];  for (long idx = 0;  idx < nt;  ++idx) pthread_create(&threads[idx],NULL,read_thread,(void *) idx);  for (long idx = 0;  idx < nt;  ++idx) pthread_join(threads[idx],NULL);  return 0; }`

Comment: @CraigEstey Can you please help with this:  I need to write a multithreaded program where threads will read words (from a function) from one of the files (e.g., Thread 1 reads words from “file1.txt”). Currently, there are four such files. I need to write a get_words() function to retrieve (up to) 10 words from a file. (the last call may be <10 words). In the end, I need to print out the number of unique words.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you so much. Can you please help with this:  I need to write a multithreaded program where threads will read words (from a function) from one of the files (e.g., Thread 1 reads words from “file1.txt”). Currently, there are four such files. I need to write a get_words() function to retrieve (up to) 10 words from a file. (the last call may be <10 words). In the end, I need to print out the number of unique words.

Comment: The fourth parameter of [`pthread_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) allows you to pass an argument of type `void *`. You could pass a pointer to a string containing the filename from which the thread should read. However, I am not sure if this is sufficient, because you mention that you want to print out "unique words" afterwards. In what way should these words be unique? Unique compared to all other words in the file? Or unique compared to all words, also the words in the other files?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel unique words from all files.

Comment: @Sudharshan: In that case, you will have to merge the results of all threads after the threads are finished, in order to determine which words are unique. In order to do this, you will either have to use a global variable/array or the main thread will have to pass additional information to the worker threads when calling `pthread_create`. If you choose the latter, then you will have the problem that you can only pass a single pointer to the thread function. Therefore, in order to pass additional information, you will have to make this pointer point to a `struct` which contains several members.

Comment: @Sudharshan: To elaborate on my previous comment: The reason why additional information will have to be passed from the main thread to the worker thread is that the main thread must tell the worker thread where the results should be writtten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different basic approaches.

1. Use thread locking and have each thread append words to a global/unified list.
2. Have each thread create its own list (faster during read phase). Have main thread create a unified list
3. Each thread creates a unique list. main thread repeatedly scans all lists and compares for uniqueness. This is an O(n^2) solution.

With (1) and (2), the main thread will sort the unified list. It can then easily find duplicates. They are O(n) solutions.

I've opted for (2).

---

Here is the code. It is *heavily* commented.

When using threads, it's often helpful to define a `struct` to contain all data relevant to a given thread.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// task control block
typedef struct {
    pthread_t tsk_tid;                      // thread id
    int tsk_wcnt;                           // word count
    char **tsk_words;                       // word list
    char *tsk_file;                         // word file
} tsk_t;

#define FORALLTSK \
    tsk_t *tsk = &tsklist[0];  tsk < &tsklist[argc];  ++tsk

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

int opt_d;                                  // 1=debug
int opt_v;                                  // 1=verbose mode

// dbgprt -- debug print
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_d) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

// printlist -- print a word list
void
printlist(char **words,int wcnt,const char *who)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("%s:\n",who);

    for (int widx = 0;  widx < wcnt;  ++widx) {
        char *word = words[widx];
        if (word != NULL)
            printf("  %s\n",words[widx]);
    }
}

// get_words -- read in word list (thread function)
void *
get_words(void *vp)
{
    tsk_t *tsk = vp;
    int cap = 0;

    FILE *fin = fopen(tsk->tsk_file,"r");
    if (fin == NULL)
        sysfault("get_words: unable to open '%s' -- %s\n",
            tsk->tsk_file,strerror(errno));

    char *tmp;
    char buf[1000];

    // get all words on all lines
    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fin) != NULL) {
        char *bp = buf;

        while (1) {
            char *word = strtok_r(bp," \t\n",&tmp);
            bp = NULL;

            // no more words on this line
            if (word == NULL)
                break;

            // increase list size if necessary
            if (tsk->tsk_wcnt >= cap) {
                cap += 10;

                tsk->tsk_words = realloc(tsk->tsk_words,
                    sizeof(*tsk->tsk_words) * cap);

                if (tsk->tsk_words == NULL)
                    sysfault("get_words: realloc error cap=%d -- %s\n",
                        cap,strerror(errno));
            }

            // add word to list
            tsk->tsk_words[tsk->tsk_wcnt++] = strdup(word);
        }
    }

    // trim word list to space actually used
    cap = tsk->tsk_wcnt;
    tsk->tsk_words = realloc(tsk->tsk_words,sizeof(*tsk->tsk_words) * cap);

    fclose(fin);

    return (void *) 0;
}

// wordcmp -- compare words
int
wordcmp(const void *vlhs,const void *vrhs)
{
    const char * const *lhs = vlhs;
    const char * const *rhs = vrhs;

    dbgprt("wordcmp: ENTER lhs=%p rhs=%p\n",lhs,rhs);

    dbgprt("wordcmp: LHS '%s'\n",*lhs);
    dbgprt("wordcmp: RHS '%s'\n",*rhs);

    int cmp = strcmp(*lhs,*rhs);

    dbgprt("wordcmp: EXIT cmp=%d\n",cmp);

    return cmp;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':  // debug printing
            opt_d = ! opt_d;
            break;

        case 'v':  // verbose printing
            opt_v = ! opt_v;
            break;
        }
    }

    // list of all threads
    tsk_t tsklist[argc];

    // launch threads
    int avidx = 0;
    for (FORALLTSK, ++avidx) {
        memset(tsk,0,sizeof(*tsk));

        tsk->tsk_file = argv[avidx];

        pthread_create(&tsk->tsk_tid,NULL,get_words,tsk);
    }

    // join threads and get total word count
    int bigcount = 0;
    for (FORALLTSK) {
        pthread_join(tsk->tsk_tid,NULL);

        bigcount += tsk->tsk_wcnt;
        dbgprt("main: ALLCOUNT bigcount=%d\n",bigcount);
    }

    // show individual lists
    if (opt_v) {
        for (FORALLTSK)
            printlist(tsk->tsk_words,tsk->tsk_wcnt,tsk->tsk_file);
    }

    // allocate the combined list
    char **biglist = calloc(bigcount,sizeof(*biglist));
    if (biglist == NULL)
        sysfault("main: unable to allocate biglist -- %s\n",strerror(errno));

    int bigidx;

    // fill in the combined list
    bigidx = 0;
    for (FORALLTSK) {
        for (int widx = 0;  widx < tsk->tsk_wcnt;  ++widx, ++bigidx)
            biglist[bigidx] = tsk->tsk_words[widx];
    }

    // print the combined list
    if (opt_v)
        printlist(biglist,bigcount,"biglist/raw");

    // sort the combined list
    qsort(biglist,bigcount,sizeof(*biglist),wordcmp);

    // print the combined list
    if (opt_v)
        printlist(biglist,bigcount,"biglist/sorted");

    // count of unique words
    int uniqcnt = 0;

    // remove duplicates from list
    const char *old = biglist[0];
    const char *cur;
    for (bigidx = 1;  bigidx < bigcount;  ++bigidx) {
        cur = biglist[bigidx];

        int cmp = strcmp(old,cur);
        dbgprt("main: CMP bigidx=%d cmp=%d old='%s' cur='%s'\n",
            bigidx,cmp,old,cur);

        if (cmp > 0)
            sysfault("main: out of sort -- old='%s' cur='%s'\n",old,cur);

        // word is unique
        if (cmp != 0) {
            ++uniqcnt;
            old = cur;
            continue;
        }

        // "nullify" a duplicate
        // NOTE: this is cheaper than doing a lot of copying elements down by
        // one slot [to squeeze out the duplicate]
        free(biglist[bigidx]);
        biglist[bigidx] = NULL;
    }

    printlist(biglist,bigcount,"biglist/unique");

    printf("unique words: %d\n",uniqcnt);

    // free up words
    for (bigidx = 0;  bigidx < bigcount;  ++bigidx, old = cur) {
        char *cur = biglist[bigidx];
        free(cur);
    }

    // free up combined list
    free(biglist);

    // free up individual task lists
    // NOTE: we've already freed the _contents_ of tsk_words in the loop above
    for (FORALLTSK)
        free(tsk->tsk_words);

    return 0;
}
```

---

I had to synthesize the test data.

I used a perl script to generate them [see below]. Here I used `./geninp -R37`

inp1.txt:

```
boodle
freeman
doodle
cain
delta
slave
abel
world
idiot
holiday
```

inp2.txt:

```
alfred
nonsense
wizard
abel
mediocre
holiday
family
hello
cain
family
```

inp3.txt:

```
picard
noble
picard
delta
able
baker
master
cain
picard
nobel
```

inp4.txt:

```
corrupt
slave
family
noble
delta
noble
boodle
galaxy
galaxy
world
```

---

Here is the output of `./program -v inp*.txt`:

```
inp1.txt:
  boodle
  freeman
  doodle
  cain
  delta
  slave
  abel
  world
  idiot
  holiday

inp2.txt:
  alfred
  nonsense
  wizard
  abel
  mediocre
  holiday
  family
  hello
  cain
  family

inp3.txt:
  picard
  noble
  picard
  delta
  able
  baker
  master
  cain
  picard
  nobel

inp4.txt:
  corrupt
  slave
  family
  noble
  delta
  noble
  boodle
  galaxy
  galaxy
  world

biglist/raw:
  boodle
  freeman
  doodle
  cain
  delta
  slave
  abel
  world
  idiot
  holiday
  alfred
  nonsense
  wizard
  abel
  mediocre
  holiday
  family
  hello
  cain
  family
  picard
  noble
  picard
  delta
  able
  baker
  master
  cain
  picard
  nobel
  corrupt
  slave
  family
  noble
  delta
  noble
  boodle
  galaxy
  galaxy
  world

biglist/sorted:
  abel
  abel
  able
  alfred
  baker
  boodle
  boodle
  cain
  cain
  cain
  corrupt
  delta
  delta
  delta
  doodle
  family
  family
  family
  freeman
  galaxy
  galaxy
  hello
  holiday
  holiday
  idiot
  master
  mediocre
  nobel
  noble
  noble
  noble
  nonsense
  picard
  picard
  picard
  slave
  slave
  wizard
  world
  world

biglist/unique:
  abel
  able
  alfred
  baker
  boodle
  cain
  corrupt
  delta
  doodle
  family
  freeman
  galaxy
  hello
  holiday
  idiot
  master
  mediocre
  nobel
  noble
  nonsense
  picard
  slave
  wizard
  world
unique words: 23
```

---

Here is the perl script that I used to generate the test files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# geninp -- generate inp*.txt files

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;

    foreach $opt (@argv) {
        next unless ($opt =~ s/^-//);

        next unless ($opt =~ s/^([a-zA-Z]+)//);
        $sym = $1;
        $sym = "opt_" . $sym;

        $opt =~ s/^=//;

        $opt = 1
            if ($opt eq "");

        printf("%s = %d\n",$sym,$opt);
        $$sym = $opt;
    }

    # random seed
    $opt_R = time()
        if ($opt_R == 0);
    $opt_R //= 1;
    srand($opt_R);
    printf("R = %d\n",$opt_R);

    $pre = "inp";

    # number of words per file
    $opt_C //= 10;

    # number of files
    $opt_F //= 4;

    # get all words
    $xf = "words::DATA";
    $xf = \*$xf;
    while ($bf = <$xf>) {
        chomp($bf);
        push(@words,$bf);
        printf("master: WORDPUSH bf='%s'\n",$bf);
    }
    die("master: no words\n")
        if (@words <= 0);

    # clean out old files
    system("rm -f " . $pre . "*.txt");

    for ($fidx = 1;  $fidx <= $opt_F;  ++$fidx) {
        dofile($fidx);
    }
}

sub dofile
{
    my($fidx) = @_;
    local($xf);

    $file = sprintf("%s%d.txt",$pre,$fidx);
    open($xf,">$file") or
        die("dofile: unable to open '$file' -- $!\n");

    printf("dofile: %s ...\n",$file);

    for ($lno = 1;  $lno <= $opt_C;  ++$lno) {
        outf(" ")
            if (($lno > 1) && $opt_j);

        $widx = int(rand(scalar(@words)));
        $word = $words[$widx];

        outf("%s",$word);

        outf("\n")
            unless ($opt_j);
    }

    outf("\n")
        if ($opt_j);

    close($xf);
}

sub outf
{

    printf($xf @_);
    printf(@_);
}

package words;
__DATA__
abel
able
baker
cain
charlie
delta
epsilon
family
galaxy
ghost
hello
idiot
politician
world
boodle
doodle
corrupt
nonsense
wisdom
wizard
quiet
noisy
picard
daithan
eladrill
madrigal
holiday
master
slave
serf
freeman
noble
peasant
nobel
alfred
magnificent
mediocre
```